# Python not outputing to file when script is run in vb program

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010

I am making a vb text editor that can run scripting code. I have successfully gotten it to run the code and show up but I would like to be able to have the output from the the code redirected to a file without having to do anything to the python code. Is that possible?

This is the code I'm using to try it but it does not write anything to the file:

Shell(compiler & " """ & fileName & " "" > C:\output.txt")

the compiler is the location of python.exe in the python install folder and the file name is the file I'm running.

The problem could also be in the way I am trying to do it with the shell command.

Comment: For starters, does it work if you enter exactly the same command-line at a command prompt?

Comment: Sorry i went out of town shortly after posting so I have not been able to work on it until now, but I tested it out and it works fine if I run it from the command prompt.

Comment: I did notice though that the C:\output.txt needs to be in quotes as well for it to be found but that didn't fix my problem in vb 2010. I thought I read somewhere that when running the shell command it does not read(don't know the actual terminology) the > sign like it would it if it were in a command prompt however I can't find where I read that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research into the the matter I found a way to make it work.

Here is the working code:

```vb
Shell("cmd.exe /c " & compiler & " """ & fileName & " "" > ""C:\output.txt"" ", vbNormalFocus)
```

So I am actually running the line through the command prompt which is being called by the shell function. My assumption was that shell function was using the command prompt to execute the string argument but I guess I was wrong. Also, just to note, the output file name is also surrounded by quotes which is different than my original post.

Comment: I understand what you are saying you need an escape key, but this string is run from the command prompt and so I guess the command prompt syntax doesn't call for an escape key.

Comment: Yes, but you're specifying the string in VB. After some searching on the topic, it looks like the \ character doesn't have to be escaped in the language.

Comment: The VB `Shell` function doesn't provide any way to redirect the stdin and stdout file streams of the executed program, and using the < and > characters to do this is a `cmd.exe` feature -- so it makes sense that your answer works.